# Oracle Managed driver and OracleAQQueue .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have little problem with upgrading my OracleDataAccess (it's old). Now we are using unmanaged driver.
Oracle suggest to move to managed version, which is also on nugget - nice. But the problem is, that this version doesn't have OracleAQQueue.

What can i do now? Should i drop managed version, and just upgrade unmanaged?
I didn't found any dll with only OracleAQQueue.
Also i didn't find 'unmanaged' version on nugget.

I rly wonder, why oracle didn't add this feature to managed version...

We are using .NET 4.8 (upgraded from 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

I added ODP.Oracle.DataAccess.x64 nuget to successfully compile the code.